# How to get the answer of a mysql request and stock it?

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

I'm building a server and i'm trying to know if a key is in my sql DB. 
I want to know if it is possible to get only the value of sql request or do I need to parse it?

```
function checkKey(key) {
   var sqlcheck = "SELECT customerID from authentification where discord_key = 
?";
console.log("in function");
DB.query(sqlcheck, [key], function (err, result) {
   if (err) throw err;
    console.log(result);
   });
}
```

this is what I get :

```
RowDataPacket { customerID: 'cus_ET5gXP7p7Tafmf' }
```

but I am looking to get only:

```
cus_ET5gXP7p7Tafmf
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `console.log(result.customerID)` will probably do the trick.

Comment: if i do that, i get 'undefined'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally

```
result[0].customerID
```

however in your example it looks like

```
result.customerID
```

Comment: i get 'undefined' when using result.customerID

Comment: how about result[0].customerID

Comment: please use  `console.log(JSON.Stringify(result));` and provide result  in your question

Comment: TypeError: JSON.Stringify is not a function 
Oh it worked for result[0]! thank you very much!

Comment: so to iterate threw every result, to find if my key exist, i can do result[i] right?

Comment: yes but can't you delegate this  work to mysql? If you know the id just pass it to your query as another constraint

Comment: yeah I'll find something to work it faster. but I have other stuff where I need to iterate threw the sql answers so it was for something else. thank you very much for your help.

Comment: I don't understand why sometimes I get undefined.         console.log(result[0].customerID); give me undefine for some column (ID for exemple or another one set to null)